# Xamarin Android Crash on Start "Got a SIGSEGV"

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, segmentation-fault, xamarin.forms

I have a Xamarin Forms App, so I'm was going to publish my app, but I found a bug, that meets only on old(2.3.7 and 4.0.4) xperia devices or emulators, so my app crashes as soons as I clicked on an app icon in menu, here is what I see in output:

```
06-10 12:46:18.344 E/mono-rt ( 2885): Stacktrace:
06-10 12:46:18.344 E/mono-rt ( 2885): 
06-10 12:46:18.344 E/mono-rt ( 2885):   at <unknown> <0xffffffff>
06-10 12:46:18.344 E/mono-rt ( 2885):   at (wrapper managed-to-native) object.wrapper_native_0x8235c890 (intptr,intptr,string,string) <IL 0x00054, 0xffffffff>
06-10 12:46:18.344 E/mono-rt ( 2885):   at Android.Runtime.JNIEnv.GetMethodID (intptr,string,string) [0x00042] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/monodroid-mavericks-monodroid-5.1-series/d419c934/source/monodroid/src/Mono.Android/src/Runtime/JNIEnv.g.cs:158
06-10 12:46:18.344 E/mono-rt ( 2885):   at Android.Runtime.JNIEnv.CreateInstance (intptr,string,Android.Runtime.JValue*) [0x00000] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/monodroid-mavericks-monodroid-5.1-series/d419c934/source/monodroid/src/Mono.Android/src/Runtime/JNIEnv.cs:377
06-10 12:46:18.344 E/mono-rt ( 2885):   at Android.Runtime.JNIEnv.CreateInstance (System.Type,string,Android.Runtime.JValue*) [0x00007] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/monodroid-mavericks-monodroid-5.1-series/d419c934/source/monodroid/src/Mono.Android/src/Runtime/JNIEnv.cs:411
06-10 12:46:18.344 E/mono-rt ( 2885):   at Android.Runtime.JNIEnv.StartCreateInstance (System.Type,string,Android.Runtime.JValue*) [0x00011] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/monodroid-mavericks-monodroid-5.1-series/d419c934/source/monodroid/src/Mono.Android/src/Runtime/JNIEnv.cs:320
06-10 12:46:18.344 E/mono-rt ( 2885):   at Android.Runtime.JNIEnv.StartCreateInstance (System.Type,string,Android.Runtime.JValue[]) [0x0001d] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/monodroid-mavericks-monodroid-5.1-series/d419c934/source/monodroid/src/Mono.Android/src/Runtime/JNIEnv.cs:326
06-10 12:46:18.344 E/mono-rt ( 2885):   at Java.Lang.Object..ctor () [0x0001c] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/monodroid-mavericks-monodroid-5.1-series/d419c934/source/monodroid/src/Mono.Android/src/Java.Lang/Object.cs:72
06-10 12:46:18.344 E/mono-rt ( 2885):   at Android.Runtime.UncaughtExceptionHandler..ctor (Java.Lang.Thread/IUncaughtExceptionHandler) [0x00000] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/monodroid-mavericks-monodroid-5.1-series/d419c934/source/monodroid/src/Mono.Android/src/Runtime/UncaughtExceptionHandler.cs:28
06-10 12:46:18.344 E/mono-rt ( 2885):   at Android.Runtime.JNIEnv.Initialize (Android.Runtime.JnienvInitializeArgs*) [0x002f4] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/monodroid-mavericks-monodroid-5.1-series/d419c934/source/monodroid/src/Mono.Android/src/Runtime/JNIEnv.cs:245
06-10 12:46:18.344 E/mono-rt ( 2885):   at (wrapper runtime-invoke) <Module>.runtime_invoke_void_intptr (object,intptr,intptr,intptr) <IL 0x00060, 0xffffffff>
06-10 12:46:18.344 E/mono-rt ( 2885): 
06-10 12:46:18.344 E/mono-rt ( 2885): Attempting native Android stacktrace:
06-10 12:46:18.344 E/mono-rt ( 2885): 
06-10 12:46:18.344 E/mono-rt ( 2885):   Could not unwind with `libunwind.so`: Cannot load library: load_library[1109]: Library '/data/data/com.telohranitel24/lib/libunwind.so' not found
06-10 12:46:18.344 E/mono-rt ( 2885):   Could not unwind with `libcorkscrew.so`: Cannot load library: load_library[1109]: Library '/data/data/com.telohranitel24/lib/libcorkscrew.so' not found
06-10 12:46:18.344 E/mono-rt ( 2885): 
06-10 12:46:18.344 E/mono-rt ( 2885):   No options left to get a native stacktrace :-(
06-10 12:46:18.344 E/mono-rt ( 2885): 
06-10 12:46:18.344 E/mono-rt ( 2885): =================================================================
06-10 12:46:18.344 E/mono-rt ( 2885): Got a SIGSEGV while executing native code. This usually indicates
06-10 12:46:18.344 E/mono-rt ( 2885): a fatal error in the mono runtime or one of the native libraries 
06-10 12:46:18.344 E/mono-rt ( 2885): used by your application.
06-10 12:46:18.344 E/mono-rt ( 2885): =================================================================
06-10 12:46:18.344 E/mono-rt ( 2885):
```

I have no idea why it happens, any ideas will be helpful, please!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While Xamarin supports all API levels of Android, Xamarin.Forms only support API level 15+ you should set your Minimum SDK to 15. Here is our documentation:

http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/xamarin-forms/introduction-to-xamarin-forms/#Requirements

This means that Xamarin.Forms supports 94% of all Android devices: https://developer.android.com/about/dashboards/index.html?utm_source=suzunone

Comment: well, on Xperia 4.0.4 it crashes too

Comment: Do you have a crash log on the Xperia 4.0.4 device? Could you run it in debug with a full stack trace as well. This would help me out to see where it is coming from.

Comment: unfortunately no, that device is far away, I'm looking for emualtor now to debug